# How can I keep an image centered vertically & horizontally AND resize it if it's size is larger than the container

Tags: html, css, size, alignment, jsfiddle

I really looked hard to find an answer to this question but I'm not finding anything quite like this.

My project is to make a lightbox effect for a gallery similar to the way facebook displays an image in a lightbox.  I want this to be responsive as possible.

I have a lightbox that holds a fixed position on a screen and has a fixed size based on the size of the display (expressed as a percent)

The lightbox is divided into a left side (which displays the image) and a right side (which displays comments and meta information.

This needs to work on a variety of aspect ratios.

If the image is smaller than the fixed size of the lightbox I want it centered vertically and horizontally.

If either of the images dimensions is larger than the fixed size of the lightbox the larger dimension should be set to the size of the light box and the smaller dimension should be set to maintain the aspect ratio.

The problem I am running into is the image is able to exceed the height of it's containers.

Any helpful solutions would be very appreciated.

Here is a link to a jsfiddle where I am attempting to do it.

http://jsfiddle.net/bawmY/2/ its a simplified version of my actual code.

Here is is incase you don't want to see it in jsfiddle

```
<div class=lb>
    <div class=lbLeftSide>
        <div class=lbImageWrapper>
           <div class=lbImageContainer>
              <img class=lbImage src="http://hockinghillscabins-lodges.com/hocking-hills-airtours/hot-air-balloon-1.jpg">
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class=lbRightSide>
         Some Content
     </div>
</div>
```

Style Sheet

```
.lb{
    position:fixed;
    width:70%;
    height:70%;
    left:10%;
    top:10%;
    border:solid black 1px;
}

.lbLeftSide{
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    width:80%%;
    background-color:green;
}
.lbRightSide{
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    width:20%;
    background-color:red;
}

.lbImageWrapper{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border:solid blue 1px;
    display:table;
}
.lbImageContainer{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border:solid pink 1px;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.lbImage{
    max-height:100%;
    max-width:100%;
    min-width:0px;
    min-height:0px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    opacity:.7;
}
```

Comment: When you take `display:table` and `display:table-cell` out of your CSS, then the image stops over-floating the wrapper. To keep the ratios of the image, CSS alone is not enough. It is a stylesheet language without the possibility of real decision making. You will need to use javascript for that.

Comment: Figured it out finally this seems to work for me.  http://jsfiddle.net/bawmY/4/